# .NET MVC3 Razor (VB!) Extensions not imported in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My extensions are not imported in my vbhtml view. I seem to be missing something somewhere.. Can anybody help please?

The module.vb:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace Areas.Admin.Models.Extensions
<Extension()> _
Public Module InputExtensions
    Public Function SelectHumanGroup(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, ByVal name As String, Optional ByVal selectedValue As String = "", Optional ByVal htmlAttributes As Object = Nothing) As MvcHtmlString
        Return helper.DropDownList(name, repo.GetGroups(), htmlAttributes)
    End Function
End Module
End Namespace
```

The view.vbhtml:

```
@Imports MySite.Areas.Admin.Models.Extensions
@ModelType MySite.Models.MyViewModel

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>


@Html.SelectHumanGroup("test")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a C# guy, but this should be valid for VB as well.
It is better though that you add your extensions via Web.config instead. That way you don't have to add them in every view.
Under your Views folder you find a Web.Config. Search for and add:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MySite.Areas.Admin.Models.Extensions" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The same error is thrown: 'SelectUserGroup' is not a member of 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'.

Comment: Sorry the error is: 'SelectUserGroup' is not a member of 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper(Of MySite.Models.MyViewModel)'. MyViewModel is passed to the view and is also referenced in the view (i updated the question..)

Comment: @Ropstah, 
you declared SelectHumanGroup but you are calling SelectUserGroup.
Could that be the problem?

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013546/cant-create-htmlhelper-methods-in-vb-mvc-app
Sorry I cannot help further, I don't really do any VB.
From the little research I did,  I cannot tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to decorate the Function and not the Model. I have something similar and it's working for me,  check this out:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace Areas.Admin.Models.Extensions
Public Module InputExtensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function SelectHumanGroup(ByVal helper As HtmlHelper, ByVal name As String, Optional ByVal selectedValue As String = "", Optional ByVal htmlAttributes As Object = Nothing) As MvcHtmlString
        Return helper.DropDownList(name, repo.GetGroups(), htmlAttributes)
    End Function
End Module
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Your module.vb NEED to be in **App_Code** directory and namespaces should be declared as it was answered above.